# Reading unsigned short array using Qt in C++

Tags: qt, binary

I'm trying to read an array of unsigned shorts using the Qt API. Unfortunately, I'm not getting the desired results.

The following code

```
        QFile in(fileName);
        int len = in.size();
        QDataStream d(&in);

        quint16 *data = new quint16[len];
        qDebug() << data[0];
        qDebug() << data[1];
        d >> data[0];
        qDebug() << data[0];
        qDebug() << data[1];
```

outputs

```
         52685 
         52685 
         13109 
         52685
```

Implying that the data is only changed at the first array position. Also, I always thought that arrays are zero initialized? Using a `QByteArray` doesn't seem to work here, that's why I'm trying to use a array of `quint16` (= unsigned shorts). Using a loop may be an option, but I'm trying to avoid a costly loop where ever possible.

So, how do fill said array (data) with the desired data from the file? Is it possible to carry the data using a `QByteArray`?

Comment: You should probably be zeroing your buffer before you attempt to use it, if you are going to be debugging like this. Also, binary data tends to "look" best in hex.

Comment: You're right. For the curious: using "qDebug() << hex << data[0];" allows to output as hex. I just tried using a loop: It is awful slow, hence not a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, `in.size()` returns the size of the file in bytes, and since you are using unsigned shorts (which are 2 bytes each), the size of your data array should be `len/2`.

Also, QDataStream is provided for serialization purposes. This means that it is mainly useful for extracting single objects at a time. See the [documentation for QDataStrean](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qdatastream.html) for more information.

You can extract the whole array without loops or copying with this code:

```
QFile in(fileName);
in.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
QByteArray byteArray = in.readAll();

quint16 *data = (quint16*) byteArray.data();
```

If you only wish to read data but never modify it, you can make your program a lot faster by changing the last line to:

```
const quint16* data = (const quint16*) byteArray.constData();
```

Keep in mind however that with this (somewhat ugly) code the pointer will only be valid for the lifetime of the QByteArray object. This usually means that you can only use `data` until the end of the function.

If you wish your data to persist longer than that, you must allocate the array and read directly into it:

```
QFile in(fileName);
in.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
int len = in.size();

quint16 *data = new quint16[len/2];
in.read((char*)data, len);
```

This way, you can access the data until you `delete[] data`.

Finally, to answer your subquestion, arrays are zero-initialized only if they are globally defined (and you shouldn't rely even on this). Arrays allocated with `new` or `malloc` are never zero-initialized for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the documentation for [`QDataStream`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdatastream.html), you'll see there are two other methods at your disposal worth considering, if you don't want to use a loop:

- [`QDataStream::readBytes`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdatastream.html#readBytes) - This will allocate a `char[]` buffer for you. Or,
- [`QDataStream::readRawData`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdatastream.html#readRawData) - This will read data into a buffer you provide.

The problem with these is they work with `char` (bytes), not `quint16` as you desire.

I would recommend using a loop to read `quint16`s. It will be the most clear code. And any respectable underlying stream implementation will be reading-ahead from the hardware into a buffer, so that your many successive `>>` calls won't be as expensive.